# How to validate an inline formset within a create view

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, view

I have an inline formset and 2 different forms within a create view of one of the forms.

All my fields in the model are blank=False and the inline formset has a minimum validation of 1.

If I try to send the form without any fields from the create view form, it displays the classic message "Please fill out this field" without rerendering the page. I want to achieve the same thing when the formset is not filled correctly. Also the same for the second form (this form is only displayed when the formset is filled based on the choice).

I am able to get the error messages re rendering the form but I'd like to do it before sending it to the server. Is it possible changing something in the model or I need to do it via js on the front?

Many thanks.

Views:

```
class SolicitacionReferenciaCreate(CreateView):

    template_name = 'microcredito/solicitacion_form.html'
    model = ContactoInfo
    fields = ['nombre', 'destinoPrestamo', 'apellido']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts/login')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        data = super(SolicitacionReferenciaCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        referencias_form_1 = ReferenciaForm()
        data['referencias_form_1'] = referencias_form_1

        if self.request.POST:
            data['plataformas'] = IngresosFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['plataformas'] = IngresosFormSet()

        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        plataformas = context['plataformas']

        with transaction.atomic():

            #ContactoInfo form
            if plataformas.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
                print("VALID")
                self.object = form.save()
                plataformas.instance = self.object
                cuposPlataformas = []
                for f in plataformas:
                    cd = f.cleaned_data
                    try:
                        score = ScorePersonas.objects.filter(idPlataforma=cd.get('idPlataforma'), numberPlataforma=cd.get('number_plataforma'),
                                                            aprobado=1)[0]
                        cuposPlataformas.append(score.cupo)
                    except:
                        try:
                            score = ScorePersonas.objects.filter(idPlataforma=cd.get('idPlataforma'), numberPlataforma=cd.get('number_plataforma'),
                                                            aprobado=0)[0]
                            cuposPlataformas.append(0)
                        except:
                            pass
                plataformas.save()

                self.object.save()
                referenciaCreado1 = Referencia.objects.create_Referencia(self.object, plataformaObjeto, rt_referenciado_1, celular_referenciado_1,
                                                                        nombre_referencia, apellido_referencia)
                referenciaCreado1.save()

            else:
                #messages.error(request, "Error")
                return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

        return render(self.request, 'microcredito/solicitacion_form.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contactForm">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                                        {{ form.source.errors }}
                                        {{ form.source }}
                                        {{ form.nombre.errors }}
                                        {{ form.nombre|as_crispy_field }}

                                        <table class="table">
                                        {{ plataformas.management_form }}

                                        {% for form in plataformas.forms %}
                                        {% if forloop.first %}
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                            <td>
                                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                                        {{ hidden }}
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                                {{ field }}
                                            </td>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        </table>

                                        <div class="form-row hide-element-form" id="ref_div_id_1">
                                          <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                            {{ referencias_form_1.numberPlataforma_referencia|as_crispy_field }}
                                          </div>
                                        </div>



                                        <input onsubmit="formSent" id="form_button" type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Formset:

```
IngresosFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ContactoInfo, IngresosPersonas,
                                             form=IngresosForm, extra=1, min_num=1, max_num=8, validate_min=True)
```